# Why is javac not complaining about more than one public class per file?

Tags: java

Here's my sample class, that compiles (and runs) with version 1.6.0_14 of Java:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sample {
  List<InnerSample> iSamples;

  public Sample() {
    iSamples = new ArrayList<InnerSample>();
    iSamples.add(new InnerSample("foo"));
    iSamples.add(new InnerSample("bar"));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Testing...");
    Sample s = new Sample();
    for (InnerSample i : s.iSamples) {
      System.out.println(i.str);
    }
  }

  public class InnerSample {
    String str;
    public InnerSample(String str) {
      this.str = str;
    }
  }
}
```

I know that you're supposed to only have one public class per file in Java, but is this more of a convention than a rule?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not allowed to have more than one **top-level** class per file. `InnerSample` is an **inner class.**

This is an example of what is prohibited in a single file:

```
public class Sample {

}

public class Sample2 {

}
```

See [JLS §7.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#26783).

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  For some reason, I had just heard that it was only one public per file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have more than one top level public class.

Nested/inner classes/interfaces/enums/@annotations don't count.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `InnerSample` is an "[inner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)" class. An inner class MUST be inside another class (and thus, inside the outer class' source file).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an inner public class

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: you may say it is a short answer but definetely not a comment. No comment can start with the word "because".